# Array out of bounds exception with JTable on mac but not windows?

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, jtable

So i'm making a sort of student database program where I can create assignments with standards and add student's grades to it.

How this basically works is I create a table and I add columns depending on which standards have been enabled, and I add rows pertaining to the student's grades in each standard. The user then edits the table then clicks save, and my program basically just takes the data from the table and adds it to the student objects and saves them in the program's directory.

For some reason, it works perfectly fine on my windows machine, but when adding grades for students, the OSX machine returns an exception saying "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5>=5" while it does what it's supposed to on the windows machine.

I made the program print the stack trace, and it printed

```
java.base/java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
java.desktop/javax.swing.able.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(Unknown Source)
```

I isolated the code in which this happens, and I found that it happens in this try catch block

```
try {
            if (elig) {
                File assignment = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/StudentDataHub/Resources/Assignments/" + labelName.getText() + ".txt");
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(assignment);
                ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);

            Assignment ass = (Assignment) oi.readObject();

            oi.close();
            fi.close();

            //actual grade adding
            for (int i = 0; i <= ass.students.size() - 1; i++) {
                String[] args = tableActualGrades.getValueAt(i, 0).toString().split(" ");  //opening files
                String studfilename = args[0].toLowerCase() + args[1].toLowerCase();

                File studfileog = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/StudentDataHub/Resources/Students/" + studfilename + ".txt");
                FileInputStream fi1 = new FileInputStream(studfileog);
                ObjectInputStream oi1 = new ObjectInputStream(fi1);

                Student stud = (Student) oi1.readObject();

                oi1.close();
                fi1.close();

                int asspos = -1;  //finding the assignment position in the stud.assignments arraylist

                for (int j = 0; j <= stud.assignments.size() - 1; j++) {
                    if (stud.assignments.get(j).getAssignmentname().equalsIgnoreCase(ass.getAssignmentname())) {
                        asspos = j;
                        j = stud.assignments.size();
                    }
                }

                boolean[] gotstandards = ass.getStandards();  //a boolean array which determines which of the standards have been enabled or disabled
                int[] actualgrades = new int[8];  

                for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) { //gets the values from the table according to which standards have been enabled/disabled and adds them to the student's grade arrays
                    if (gotstandards[j]) {
                        actualgrades[j] = Integer.parseInt(tableActualGrades.getValueAt(i, j + 1).toString());
                    } else {
                        actualgrades[j] = -1;
                    }
                }

                actualgrades[5] = Integer.parseInt(tableActualGrades.getValueAt(i, tableActualGrades.getColumnCount() - 3).toString());
                actualgrades[6] = Integer.parseInt(tableActualGrades.getValueAt(i, tableActualGrades.getColumnCount() - 2).toString());
                actualgrades[7] = Integer.parseInt(tableActualGrades.getValueAt(i, tableActualGrades.getColumnCount() - 1).toString());    //these lines set the grades for the required standards

                stud.assignments.get(asspos).setGrades(actualgrades);

                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/StudentDataHub/Resources/Students/" + studfilename + ".txt"));
                ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);

                oo.writeObject(stud);

                oo.close();
                fo.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: " + e.getStackTrace()[0] +"; " + e.getStackTrace()[1], "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Again, this doesn't throw any errors on my machine, but when testing a distribution of it on a mac it throws these errors that not only do I not understand, but I also struggle to resolve as I dont own a mac myself.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpta5.png) is a screenshot of how the table looks (I only included the code for one of the tabs, but it's basically the same code with different variables for the others)

Comment: Can you tell us which line is throwing the exception? Also, can you tell us whether there is any installation/system variables involved with your project?

Comment: @LajosArpad I'm using System.getProperty("user.home"), which I doubt is the cause as it works fine at other points in the program. How would I catch the line which is throwing the exception? Without using try catch it appears in the output in my IDE but I'm not sure how to display that information when I'm using a try catch statement in a build of an app.

Comment: You can do it using a debugger and going line-by-line with it until you reach the line inside the try block which throws the Exception.

Comment: What should I do if I don't have a Mac with which to edit my program with? I have a Windows PC, I'm just testing the app by sending it to some friends

Comment: You can ask someone to allow you to test your program on their computer, not necessarily Mac, because the OS difference is not necessarily relevant, at least we do not factually know about it. You can use a lab to test this on another computer. Or you can install a virtual machine (like VirtualBox) on your computer, install Mac on this virtual machine and debug on it. Or you can install a Mac on your PC as well. There are several options to solve this issue.

Comment: Alright, I tried what you suggested (I borrowed a friend's Mac to code in that instead) and I wasn't able to replicate the same bug. I then tested it on another friend's computer, and once again, the bug didn't appear and the program functioned as expected. I don't know what happened the first times I was testing it, but I guess it's not an issue anymore? Either way, thanks for the help.

Comment: It's possible that there was an issue which was fixed "by accident" since then.